# Having a decode error while using a shell command with a python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, python-3.7

I'm doing a python script from instructions given to me by a supervisor. I figured out how to call Shell commands through the script using the `asyncio` library and I copied the command to run them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html). It works for most of the commands I want to use. The problem comes from the ones linked to linkerd and I'm not even sure about what they are supposed to even do. Commands in question:

```
./linkerd install --ha --ignore-cluster | grep image: | grep linkerd | sed -e 's/^ .*images: //* | sort | uniq >> linkerd_images.txt
./linkerd viz install --ha --skip-checks | grep images: | sed -e 's/^ .*images: //* | sort | uniq >> linkerd_images.txt
```

The error code I'm getting is:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 49: invalid continuation byte`. From what I can tell from other posts here, this error code usually means that you're not using the proper decode method (most people had this problem while trying to open PDFs) and they had to change their `f = open('file.txt', 'utf-8')` or something like that. The problem here is that I'm opening the file with python and I'm not sure how to impact that. I would usually look into the command and try to do it with pure python, but this one uses LinkerD's binary so I can't really do that (or at least I don't think so). How do I approach this or how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with these kinds of commands but I see that it mentions images. Is it possible that the output of this command is trying to read an image and parse it into text? That's the only reason I can think of that would cause it to fail.

Comment: I think so. I know that there's a list of images in linkerd_images.txt and it has to do with it. I just personally never did bash before so I have no idea what it's actually trying to do

Comment: I would suggest looking through the docs for the commands you're using to try to determine the output types then.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found today. The problem was that my apostrophe was a French apostrophe (or another symbol resembling that) which wasn't recognized by sed. The person who sent me the command didn't take into account his keyboard layout and I copy pasted it in my code without second thought. I also didn't write it correctly here because stack overflow is on my personal PC so I was eyeing the code from my work laptop. If you ever find yourself here, make sure all of the symbols are authentic. Someone from the ubuntu stackexchange made me run `hexdump -C [name of the script]`. This gives you the hex value of every character in your file. Scroll down to that part of the command and double check that every character has its proper hex value.